# Spring Joint 2D (maybe) causing transform.position errors

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I know the title might be misleading after you see what is the problem, but I really don't know how to name this issue.
The first picture shows the problem.[image: issue]

The white line shows the distance between the player and the gameobject called hook. The blue sprite sphere close to the hook is the SpringJoint2D.connectedBody.

They both (the white line and the blue sprite) are working with the same value: hook.transform.position.

Here is the code snippets which I believe are causing problems or at least reveal the most:

SpringJoint2D snippet:

```css
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            hook = FindClosestObject(radius, "Hook");
            if(hook != null)
            {
                joint.enabled = true;
                joint.connectedBody = hook;
                joint.connectedAnchor = hook.transform.position;
                Debug.Log("Click.");
                Debug.Log(hook);
            }
            
        }
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
        {
            joint.enabled = false;
            joint.connectedBody = null;
        }
```

Debug.DrawLine snippet:

```css
if (hook != null)
        {
            joint.distance = Vector3.Distance(hook.transform.position, transform.position) / 2;
            Debug.DrawLine(transform.position, hook.transform.position);
        }
```

And here is the whole code:

```css
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    
    public float radius;

    private SpringJoint2D joint;
    private Rigidbody2D hook = new Rigidbody2D();


    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        joint = GetComponent<SpringJoint2D>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        //touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            hook = FindClosestObject(radius, "Hook");
            if(hook != null)
            {
                joint.enabled = true;
                joint.connectedBody = hook;
                joint.connectedAnchor = hook.transform.position;
                Debug.Log("Click.");
                Debug.Log(hook);
            }
            
        }
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
        {
            joint.enabled = false;
            joint.connectedBody = null;
        }
        //foreach (Touch touch in Input.touches)
        //{

        //}
        if (hook != null)
        {
            joint.distance = Vector3.Distance(hook.transform.position, transform.position) / 2;
            Debug.DrawLine(transform.position, hook.transform.position);
        }

        
    }

    private void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        Gizmos.color = Color.green;
        Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(transform.position, radius);
        if (hook != null) 
            Gizmos.DrawLine(transform.position, hook.transform.position);
    }

    public Rigidbody2D FindClosestObject(float radius, string tag)
    {
        GameObject[] gos;
        gos = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag(tag);
        Rigidbody2D closest = null;
        float distance = radius;
        Vector3 position = transform.position;
        foreach (GameObject go in gos)
        {
            Vector3 diff = go.transform.position - position;
            float curDistance = diff.sqrMagnitude;
            if (curDistance < distance)
            {
                closest = go.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
                distance = curDistance;
            }
        }
        return closest;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I was just stupid.

There is no need to assign the connectedAnchor if you also asign the connectedRigidbody2D
The connectedAnchor is the offset from the connectedRigidbody2D's position...